# Chrome extension id is built new everytime I package the extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to host a chrome extension by myself and I want the extension to autoupdate.
Every time I pack the extension an new extension id is generated. But if the extension id changes the autoupdate stops working because the id differs from the one in the updates.xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first time you package an extension Chrome creates a pem file for signing future release. Use that pem key when packaging the extension and it will keep the same ID.

Comment: That's what I do. I use the extension.pem file to sign. I sign from the package extension dialog on the extension tab in dev mode.